# Querying a DynamoDB‎ table

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I've the below table in my DynamoDB‎.

```
ID   Author     storyName
1   AuthorOne   Story 1
2   AuthorOne   Story 2
3   AuthorTwo   Story 1
4   AuthorTwo   Story 2
```

I'm new to DynamoDB‎ and I need a query that will retrieve all the author names. If it was a regular database (RDBMS) I would have used the query as below.

```
select DISTINCT Author from tableName;
```

How can I do this it in DynamoDB‎?

Answer (score 1):

You can scan the table, projecting the ID and Author attributes only, and then `.map(item -> item.getS("Author")` from Item to Author attribute and `.collect(Collectors.toSet())`. If you do not want to scan the table each time you need to find out the list of authors, you will need to stream updates to your table to AWS ElasticSearch or some other platform that supports counting.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB doesn't have in-build feature like SQL to get the distinct values of an attribute.

However, you can use **AWS EMR service** which integrates with DynamoDB to run the SQL like `Distinct` queries.

**Hive Queries:-**

All of the feature types (feature_class) in alphabetical order:

```
SELECT DISTINCT feature_class
FROM ddb_features
ORDER BY feature_class;
```

[Refer the data in DynamoDB table with Apache Hive on Amazon EMR](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.Tutorial.QueryDataInDynamoDB.html)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, DynamoDB does not support SQL queries or any other way of achieving that. The querying capacity of DynamoDB is very limited. You can specify partition key and optionally sort key for a table to filter rows, and that's it.

A service called [Rockset](https://rockset.com) can tail your DynamoDB tables and provide full-featured SQL on them.

This blog talks about how you can use Rockset to query your data in DynamoDB tables using SQL: https://rockset.com/blog/running-fast-sql-on-dynamodb-tables/

Full disclosure: I work on the engineering team @ Rockset.